# Can I add my own fields to JSON files in the keystore directory?

Tags: go-ethereum, wallets, accounts, keystore

I need to add a few fields to JSON v3 wallet file, can I do it ? What is Ethereum's policy on this?

For example, to add account name I would do something like this:

```
{
    "address": "4c437d8f70dd161676010e8900016d23f5f5056a",
    "crypto": {
        "cipher": "aes-128-ctr",
        .... etc .....
     },
    "user_data": {
         "account_name":"All my life savings",
         ... etc ...
    }
}
```

so, basically , I would add a section to the JSON file called `user_data` where all the info about the account would go. In theory, doing this would be compatible with other wallets if the wallets are not `strict` about JSON format, so I guess it is doable. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Yes that's fine because go-ethereum will create a new keystore file when you create a new wallet and won't override existing ones. Re-encrypting with a different password will also create a new keystore file.

Comment: what if I put my extended JSON file into `keystore` directory using OS ? will it work?

Comment: @Nulik not sure, you may try it. Always back it up